# One-on-one and group chat query for conversations in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have been working on a MongoDB query that keeps getting more and more complicated. I've opened a couple of threads already, but I feel like it would be better to explain my entire case and adjust the query all at once to fit all my needs, because I feel like I need to change everything as soon as I want to introduce more and more conditions.

So, for my case, I want to create a chat application. Users can have one-on-one conversations, as well as group chats with up to 25 people. The idea behind my database is to keep a `conversations` document and a `messages` document which are linked to each other using the _id from the conversation. This is my `conversations` document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "n" : "Example Group Chat",
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "admin",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "l" : 1581863346,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580581922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "9",
            "j" : 1580593922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "3",
            "j" : 1580594920,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "8",
            "j" : 1580594999,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e39d5d740713a43aeef5b26"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "2",
            "j" : 1580580922,
            "i" : "1",
            "r" : "member",
            "a" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see a group chat (first) and a one-on-one chat (second). Group chats can have names (n), one-on-one chats not. Every conversation has an array of members, which stores the userID (uID), the join date (j), the left date (l), an invited by userID field (i), a role field (r) and an active field (a). I probably won't need the "active" field, as I have a join/left timestamp, but still. I'll probably delete it later, so that field probably won't be included.

Next, I have my `messages` document as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4917bca59ce44ef2770086"),
    "c_ID" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "msg" : "Whats good?",
    "fromID" : "1",
    "__v" : 0,
    "t" : 1582369525,
    "d" : {
        "4" : 1582369525
    },
    "r" : {
        "4" : 1582369525
    }
}
```

This holds the message itself (msg), the user who sent it (fromID), the timestamp in UNIX Epoch (t) and subcollections of deliveries (d) and reads (r) and of course the conversation ObjectID (c_ID).

I currently have the following query, after much help here on StackOverflow:

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "messages",
        foreignField: "c_ID",
        localField: "_id",
        as: "messages"
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$messages"
    },
    {
      "$sort": {
        "messages.t": -1
      }
    },
    {
      "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "lastMessage": {
          "$first": "$messages"
        },
        "allFields": {
          "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            "$allFields",
            {
              "lastMessage": "$lastMessage"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        messages: 0
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        "members.uID": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "lastMessage.t": 1
      }
    },
    {
      $limit: 10
    },
    {
      $project: {
        members: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$members",
                as: "member",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $ne: [
                        "$$member.uID",
                        "1"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $or: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$member.l",
                            undefined
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $lt: [
                            "$$member.l",
                            "$$member.j"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
        },
        n: 1,
        lastMessage: 1
      }
    }
  ])
```

I am facing a couple of problems with the above:

- I need to make sure the participant is still allowed to see the conversation. If they leave, and thus the `l` field is set on the member with a timestamp greater than the join date, the user can still see that conversation, but the last message has to be before the left timestamp. For example: member with userID 4 has left the group chat, but the chat is still visible in his overview, with messages BEFORE his left date (`1581863346`)
- I want to make sure the lastMessage is always the last message BEFORE someone has left. Again, in the above example, the user with userID 4 is only allowed to see messages with timestamps lower than his left date (so, in this specific case, before `1581863346`)
- **EDIT:** This is more of a nice to have an not necessary for the core functionality, but it would be great to include a `memberCount` field which is just the number of users, based on the same criteria: no left date (undefined) or join date larger than left date, so the retrieve the “actual” number of members currently in the group.

Any ideas on how to improve my query to include the two above conditions? Or, also, is there a way to optimize my query for performance? Cheers!

By the way: this might be important, but I guess this makes sense if you've read all the way through: this query is ment to be used in the overview of all your active conversations, sorted by timestamp. What you'll see first if you open Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp, let's say.

EDIT: Based on the answer of @Tunmee I found two more conditions that needed to be applied:
 - The lastMessage should be posted not only **before** the left date (`l`), but also after the join date (`j`).
 - I want to return only the conversations in which a lastMessage is retrieved, so only when there is a chat message to be shown to the user.

I came up with the following query. Does this look good? Any concerns?

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "members.uID": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      user: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$members",
              as: "member",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "messages",
      let: {
        user: "$user",
        conversatoinId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$c_ID",
                    "$$conversatoinId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $lt: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$user.l",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$user.j"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: true,
                    else: {
                      $lt: [
                        "$t",
                        "$$user.l"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$t",
                    "$$user.j"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },

        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "t": -1
          },

        }
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lastMessage: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$messages",
          0
        ]
      },
      n: 1,
      members: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "lastMessage.t": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      members: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$members",
          as: "member",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "4"
                ]
              },
              {
                $or: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      undefined
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lt: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      "$$member.j"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      memberCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$members",
            as: "member",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$member.uID",
                    "4"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $or: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$member.l",
                        undefined
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lt: [
                        "$$member.l",
                        "$$member.j"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      n: 1,
      lastMessage: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      lastMessage: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  }
])
```

**EDIT: As far as I can tell, it all looks good at the moment. The only thing I'm missing now is something to catch the following situation:
Imagine there is a group chat with 20 members. The name of the chat is "Funky Fridays". userID 4 joins that group chat (I set the `j` (join) field to `1582475543` (timestamp), participates for twee weeks and then leaves (I set the `l` (left) field to `1583685143` (timestamp). This will all work fine. However, how can I add userID 4 again to the same group chat 1 week later (timestamp `1584289943`) and make sure userID 4 can see the lastMessage IF it is either between the first time he joined/left OR if it's posted after he joined again?**

I would like to be able to add the same user more than once to the members array, but with different `j` (and `l`) fields, and then query the lastMessage to be between one of them, which would allow for what I want to do as described above.

Comment: Just to clarify, when a user leaves a group, he should not be able to see *newer* messages but still be able to see old messages(messages with timestamps lower than his left date)?

Comment: @Tunmee Correct. So in this overview there will only be one message, the last one (lastMessage). The overview will have all conversations listed in a table with username or group name, underneath the last message they are allowed to see, and the time it was sent. So, like Facebook Messenger pretty much.

Comment: @Tunmee I understand your confusion based on my first point of concern. To be entirely clear: the user can still see the conversation in the overview, but the "last message" has to be the last one before he left (or it will probably be something like "You left this conversation").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "members.uID": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      user: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$members",
              as: "member",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "messages",
      let: {
        user: "$user",
        conversatoinId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$c_ID",
                    "$$conversatoinId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $lt: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$user.l",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        "$$user.j"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: true,
                    else: {
                      $lt: [
                        "$t",
                        "$$user.l"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },

        },
        {
          $sort: {
            "t": -1
          },

        }
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      lastMessage: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$messages",
          0
        ]
      },
      n: 1,
      members: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      lastMessage: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "lastMessage.t": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  },
  {
    $project: {
      members: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$members",
          as: "member",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$member.uID",
                  "1"
                ]
              },
              {
                $or: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      undefined
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $lt: [
                      "$$member.l",
                      "$$member.j"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      n: 1,
      lastMessage: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Pipeline Explanation:

- `match`: This matches only the conversations that the user is a part of;
- `addFields`: This adds a "user" field to each conversation document. The user field stores the member document(from the members array) of the particular user we are aggregating data for.
- `lookup`: This is just like the `lookup` stage in the pipeline you posted, however, this one uses the `lookup#pipeline` and `lookup#let` options to add some constraints to the messages that are loaded.
- `lookup#let`: I'm basically declaring variables to use in the `lookup#pipeline`.
- `lookup#pipeline#match`: This sub-pipeline stage ensures the message document: (1) has a conversation ID(`c_ID`) that matches the id of the conversation document. (2) if the user has left the channel i.e `$$user.l` is less than `$$user.j`, the message timestamp must be lower than the date the user left the channel. Notice the use of the `ifNull` operator to set the `$$user.l` field as 0 if it was null i.e the user has not left the group at all.
- `lookup#pipeline#sort`: This sorts the messages that are passed in from the match stage in descending order. This is added so that we can easily get the last message;
- `project`: Reshapes the document to include the `lastMessage` field and remove the `messages` field.
- `sort`: This is the same as what was in the pipeline you posted.
- `limit`: This is the same as what was in the pipeline you posted.
- `project`: This is the same as what was in the pipeline you posted.

Comment: Whoa. Seems to work great. Need to test a bit further of course to see if everything is covered, but it looks promising. One thing I noticed: when there is no message before the join date, the conversation gets returned but without a lastMessage attached to it. Is there any way to remove that specific conversation, so it won't be shown in the results? Only when the first message is available, I would like it to be included in the list.

Comment: Also, one more caveat: the message should be posted before the left date, which works fine. But it also should be posted after the join date. So earlier messages, before a user was added, should not be visible to that user. Is that also possible?

Comment: I fixed my last comment by adding `{ $gt: [ "$t", "$$user.j" ] }` to the `$and` operator. **However, still wondering about the first comment: how can I only show conversations where a lastMessage is found? And thus is not an empty chat?**

Comment: Another thing I'm wondering: is there any way I can have a user join a group chat, participate for 2 weeks, then leave, and 2 months later join again? Would it be possible to just add another element to the members array with the same userID? I would like to be able to retrieve messages from within the first two weeks, as well as the new ones after joining again.

Comment: I have edited my question with a couple of things I tried to match my needs mentioned above in the comments here. Can you take a look to tell me if you have any concerns?

Comment: For the first comment about getting only aggregation results with a `lastMessage` field attached to it, you can add a `match` stage after the `project` stage(adding the `lastMessage` field), the `match` stage would filter out any document without a `lastMessage` field. I would update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi again, I figured that out. Only have one question left, for which I updated the original post. It’s about allowing joining/leaving multiple times and retrieving the “correct” last message. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: To clarify, does this sound like a good description of the feature you want to achieve: *Given that a user can join, leave, and rejoin a group as many times as he/she wants, compose an aggregation pipeline to fetch all the messages that were posted in the group just when the user was active in the group i.e messages that were posted when the user was not in the group won’t be included in the result.*

Comment: Precisely. That’s exactly what I’m looking for. So I think I should include the same userID among the users multiple times, but from that point forward I’m out of ideas.

Comment: Ok. This new desired feature is cool, however, it’s different from what the current query/feature is doing. The current query is getting the `lastMessage` in each conversation so it doesn’t matter if the user has left and rejoined the group a thousand times, having the last left and joined time stamp is enough.

Comment: The new feature is more about getting all the messages in a (single) conversation where the user might have joined and rejoined a thousand times. There is no need to fuse the potential query for this feature into what already exists, It’s a different feature in a different use case, I would suggest asking a different question for it. And maybe you can accept this answer-post since it answers/fixes the actual question that was posted.

Comment: I agree. Thanks a bunch!